# Find the slope of the line go through a point such that the area between the graph and the line is minimum

Tags: calculus, functions, area

> If $a$ is the slope of $(L)$ that go through point $(-1,2)$ and $f(x)=x^2$ then find $a$ such that the area between the graph and the line is minimum.

For what I thought, the area is minimum if the line tangent to the graph because that mean the area is $0$. For the above problem, the point $(-1,2)$ is inside the graph so there can't be a line that tangent to it ( I think ). But still for what I did, I take $a=f'(-1)$ which is $a=-2$. I dunno if what I did is right or wrong at all. Please help

Comment: No, $f’(-1)$ has nothing to do with it. In fact $f’(x)$ has nothing to do with it. I would just use a direct method. Find the points of intersection of line L and $f(x)=x^2$ in terms of $a$ and then find the equation of the area between L and $f(x)$ in terms of a. Then find the value of $a$ that minimises this expression (of the area).

Comment: By "(L)" do you mean "line"?  If so, why not use "line"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note I am using notation $m$ for the slope instead of $a$.

If you have two points $A$ and $B$ with $x-$coordinates $x = a$ and $x =b$ ($b \gt a$) on the parabola $y=x^2$, area of parabola under the straight line between these two points can be found as below.

For points on the line segment $AB$, $y -a^2 = \frac{b^2-a^2}{b-a} (x-a) \implies y = (a+b)x - ab$

So the area is $A = \int_a^b ((a+b)x-ab - x^2) \ dx = \frac{1}{6}(b-a)^3$ ...(i)

Now for a line with slope $m$ through point $(-1, 2)$, the equation of the line will be

$y-2 = m(x+1)$ and $x-$coordinates of its intersection with parabola $y=x^2 \ $ is given by,

$x^2 - mx - (m+2) = 0 \implies x = \frac{m \pm \sqrt{m^2+4m+8}}{2}$

Plugging in $(i)$, $A = \frac{1}{6}(m^2+4m+8)^{3/2}$

So if we minimize $(m^2+4m+8)$, we minimize the area. We can rewrite $m^2+4m+8$ as $(m+2)^2+4$ which shows that the minimum area occurs at $m = -2$.

Comment: So the answer is really $-2$. Do you think my solution is just a coincidence that it has the same answer or it is right?

Comment: No I do not think it is coincidental. I think for lines going through a given point $(m,n)$ in the interior of parabola $y=x^2$ (at least), the min area is bound by the line which has the same slope as the tangent to the parabola at $(m,m^2)$. You can in fact take a generic point $(m,n)$ and plug in my working to check.